# Automorphisms of del Pezzo surface of degree $1$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have som problems with understanding of finite subgroups $G$ of $Aut(S)$,where $S$ del Pezzo surface of degree $1$. I consider case, when $k = \mathbb{Q}$. I don't understand why $Aut(S)$  embedding to $GL_2(\mathbb{Q})$ : $Aut(S) \hookrightarrow GL_2(\mathbb{Q})$.